# wordpress Captcha Error: The reCAPTCHA wasn’t entered correctly

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, plugins, recaptcha, captcha

I suddenly keep receiving this error "The reCAPTCHA wasn’t entered correctly" for all wordpress and woocommerce and contact forms in my website. reCAPTCHA was working with no problem for more than 2 years. now none of the reCAPTCHA plugins works. things I have checked are:

disabling all plugins and testing several times.
changing theme to wordpress default theme.
checking site key and secret key.
trying captcha 3.

I have a website in subdirectory. same problem exists for the second website. two websites have different themes and plugins.
I will appreciate you if you have any solution or idea to solve this problem.

Comment: debug errors ? any console errors ? Its kinda imposible just to guess here. what plugin you use for recaptcha ?

Comment: I enabled wp_debug but no errors displayed, google captcha by bestwebsoft but theme contact form other captcha plugins also did not work.

Comment: what about consonle ?

Comment: for captcha by bestwebsoft i have this error in console: [DOM] Found 2 elements with non-unique id #gglcptch: <input type=​"hidden" name=​"gglcptch" value id=​"gglcptch">​ for others nothing.

Comment: if you use contact form 7 have u turned on the recaptcha there ?

Comment: No. I don't use contact form 7. I create my contact forms using theme forms. enfold theme. enfold has some settings for google captcha for it's own forms. other places that i use captcha for are wordpress and woocommerce forms and wp comments. the only plugin that works right now is captcha 4w. I tested it and it seems to work. but other captcha plugins are not working on both websites.

Comment: then its more like a theme bug not plugin. Contact the devs is your best option here.

Comment: unfortunately i have the same problem with default theme.